# Passing an array of integers as a parameter of an (inline) user defined function (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, functions, entity-framework, table-valued-parameters

I have TBV function . Like this

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Functiont]
(
 @accessibleIds   ListAccesableIds READONLY
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(   
SELECT d.*, b.Name AS Name, ps.Name AS PaymentSystemName, c.UserName AS UserName, c.FirstName AS ClientFirstName, c.LastName AS LastName, c.Number AS DocumentNumber, c.Id
FROM Document AS d
JOIN System AS ps ON d.SystemId = ps.Id
JOIN Client AS c ON c.Id = d.ClientId
LEFT JOIN Shop AS b ON b.Id = d.ShopId
WHERE d.OperationTypeId IN (2, 4, 5) AND c.Type = 1
)
```

I want to pass to this function List containing integers.I was bale to create table valued type but here is the question how could i pass List input parameter to the function?I know that i could pass lists via ADO.Net to the SP very easly but my problem regards to the Entity Framework and TBF functions

I am calling this function through Entity Framework 6 the approach which we used was database first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On SQL-Server 2014 you can take advantatge of [TYPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql) (alias data type), and pass it as a parameter of an Inline UDF simulating an array of integer, or any other tabular data.

Keep in mind you must use READONLY.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTest') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.MyTest;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyFunction') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction;
GO

IF TYPE_ID ('dbo.Mytype') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TYPE dbo.Mytype;
GO

CREATE TYPE dbo.Mytype AS TABLE (Id int);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTest (Id int, Val char(3));
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTest VALUES (1,'V1'),(2,'V2'),(10,'V10'),(11,'V11');
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction(@Table MyType READONLY)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM   MyTest
    WHERE  Id IN (SELECT Id FROM @Table)
);
GO
```

```
DECLARE @myTable Mytype;
INSERT INTO @myTable(Id) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5);

SELECT * FROM MyFunction(@myTable);

| Id | Status |
|:--:|:------:|
|  1 |   V1   |
|  2 |   V2   |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a816fdc47a90e0af1c8173271b61c152)*